# 'When' syntax issue in Kotlin notification

Tags: kotlin, variables, syntax, notifications

I am overriding `Notification` and it has a variable 'when'

[when documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD2oh.png)

But, in my overridden Notification, when I try to set when to something like `when = 5.toLong()` it bugs the compiler because `when` is a word that means something in kotlin syntax.
How can I assign the value to `when`?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are wondering about how to reference the `when` property of the `Notification` class (documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#when)) in Kotlin. Because the Android API for `Notification` is written in Java, it can make use of `when` as a token for a variable name. However, as you've indicated, Kotlin has a reserved keyword `when` as a logical block similar to `if ... else if`. In order to reference the Java defined `when` property, you must use the [escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin), which in this case would be `` `when` ``.

Comment: thank you and pretend i thumbsup your comment xcept i cant because im a noob

Comment: You can accept the answer that solved your problem and was most helpful by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

> why did they do it like that, lol?

Per the screenshot you posted of the documentation, the `when` attribute of Notification was added in API level 1. Which was circa 2009. Long before `when` in Kotlin or Kotlin itself even existed.

> and what is solution?

Follow [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification) and use [the Builder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder) that has a [setWhen](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setWhen(long)) method

Or [learn about escaping Java variables that are Kotlin keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin).

Comment: Please be respectful in answers... your use of lol, rofl, and lmao do not come off as being respectful, and while the author originally used similar abbreviations, it is quite obvious that the question needs refinement to fit the community guidelines.

Comment: I was joking around to play along with the OP's own style, but fair. Edit accepted.